# How to get all transactons of a specific address?

Tags: web3js, web3j, mysql

I am trying to retrieve all transactions for a particular address at once.

My current approach is to collect all transactions of all blocks in MySQL DB and issue a query like "SELECT * FROM table WHERE from = ***** OR to = ***********;".
However, collecting all transactions of all blocks would require too long a time.
Is there any way to get all transactions issued by a particular address in a much shorter time?

I'm using web3js and web3j.

Comment: What blockchain are we talking about here?

Comment: @Sky this is Ethereum stack exchange

Comment: Your node surely has this ability, but will it let you use it? A lot of public nodes don't allow heavy queries through web3. You might want to run your own node, which indexes all the transactions using your own computing power

Comment: I have a private node(Geth) running in full sync mode on my home PC.

Comment: use the website called Dune Analytics

Comment: if you have private chain then you must have your own explorer service, there must be open source project for that. `geth` doesn't index transactions by sender

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://www.etherscan.io for this approach.

Enter the address in the search bar and then open the transactions tab. under Transactions in the menu, there is a text `Latest 25 from a total of xxx transactions`.

Click on the total number (xxx) and this will bring you to a page showing complete list of transactions. On the bottom, there is an `Export to CSV` option.

Answer (score 0):

Use a node as a service. Alchemy has a [endpoint](https://docs.alchemy.com/reference/alchemy-getassettransfers) that does the job really quickly. They simply have more hardware capabilities than you can possibly have at your home and its free. If you insist in using your own computer you could explore [TrueBlocks](https://trueblocks.io/) or some other local explorer.

Answer (score 0):

I am actually working on an `API` that much more convenient / faster to use for this task than web3.js.

Just run the request below (and replace the placeholder address `0x7a250d5630B4cF539739dF2C5dAcb4c659F2488D` with the address you have in mind in both places). This should get you all transactions an address has made in a single request (if there are more than 100,000 transactions you can use the cursor to fetch the next page of results - docs here: syve.ai).

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://api.syve.ai/v1/transactions' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
        "filter": {
            "type": "or",
            "params": {
                "filters": [
                    {
                        "type": "eq",
                        "params": {
                            "field": "to_address",
                            "value": "0x7a250d5630B4cF539739dF2C5dAcb4c659F2488D"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "eq",
                        "params": {
                            "field": "from_address",
                            "value": "0x7a250d5630B4cF539739dF2C5dAcb4c659F2488D"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        "options" : [
            {
                "type" : "size",
                "params" : {
                    "value" : 100000
                }
            }
        ]
    }'
```